# simplexml_load_file тире и массив

Tags: php

Интересная ситуация получается. Использую simplexml_load_file

вывожу:

```
echo $offer->{'floor'}; всё ок
echo $offer->image[$x]; всё ок
```

А ВОТ С ЭТИМ НЕ ОК ((((((((((

```
echo  $offer->{'room-space[$x]'};
```

уже всё перепробовал
и в переменную каждую часть переводил ничего не помогает (

Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Добавьте пример XML для теста. Предполагаю, что вам нужен `$offer->{'room-space'}[$x]`

Comment: Ваш код оказался самым более верным, но ошибкой была моя невнимательность. $offer->{'room-space'}[$ii]->value; Спасибо!!!

Answer (score -1):

`echo $offer->{'room-space['.$x.']'};`

либо

`echo $offer->{"room-space[$x]"};`

PS Ну еще непонятно про `[` `]` - это у вас "указатель" на массив PHP или прям тег с этими элементами?

Comment: если вам не понятно оставьте коментарий под вопросов, зачем пальцем в небо отвечать?